# Insert customFields using the Administration

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have created a plugin in the adminstration and I want set value of customFields for a specific product.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the product repository to fetch the product, set the custom fields value and persist it using the repository again.

Simplified example:

```js
Component.register('my-component', {
    template,

    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],

    computed: {
        productRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('product');
        },
    },

    methods: {
        async updateProduct(productId, value) {
            const product = await this.productRepository.get(productId, Shopware.Context.api);
            
            if (!product) {
                return;
            }
            
            product.customFields.my_custom_field = value;

            this.productRepository.save(product, Shopware.Context.api);
        }
    },
});
```